# unrolling loops macros needed

Tags: c, m4

Consider the following code:

```
extern int conn_fds[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern int fl_conn_indexes[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern int fl_req_bufs[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern struct epoll_event estab_events[MAX_THREADS];
extern req_buf_t req_bufs[MAX_REQ_BUFS];
extern int fl_req_bufs_top;
extern int conn_statuses[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern int fl_conn_indexes_top;
extern  tcpl_nc_t nc_http_list;
extern struct sockaddr_in conn_addresses[MAX_CLIENTS];

void accept_connections(unsigned int num_conns) {
    int fds[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn_idx=0;
    int new_bottom;
    socklen_t slenghts[MAX_THREADS];
    void *labels1[MAX_THREADS] = {&&a0,&&a1,&&a2,&&a3,&&a4,&&a5,&&a6,&&a7,&&a8,&&a9,&&a10,&&a11,&&a12,&&a13,&&a14,&&a15};
    void *labels2[MAX_THREADS] = {&&b0,&&b1,&&b2,&&b3,&&b4,&&b5,&&b6,&&b7,&&b8,&&b9,&&b10,&&b11,&&b12,&&b13,&&b14,&&b15};
    void *labels3[MAX_THREADS] = {&&c0,&&c1,&&c2,&&c3,&&c4,&&c5,&&c6,&&c7,&&c8,&&c9,&&c10,&&c11,&&c12,&&c13,&&c14,&&c15};

    new_bottom=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    if (new_bottom<=0) return;

    goto *labels1[num_conns];
 a15:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 1]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 1];
 a14:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 2]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 2];
 a13:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 3]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 3];
 a12:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 4]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 4];
 a11:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 5]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 5];
 a10:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 6]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 6];
 a9:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 7]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 7];
 a8:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 8]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 8];
 a7:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 9]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- 9];
 a6:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-10]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-10];
 a5:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-11]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-11];
 a4:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-12]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-12];
 a3:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-13]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-13];
 a2:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-14]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-14];
 a1:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-15]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-15];
 a0:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-16]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top-16];

    fl_conn_indexes_top=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    goto *labels2[num_conns];
 b15:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 1]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 1]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 1]);
 b14:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 2]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 2]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 2]);
 b13:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 3]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 3]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 3]);
 b12:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 4]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 4]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 4]);
 b11:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 5]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 5]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 5]);
 b10:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 6]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 6]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 6]);
 b9:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 7]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 7]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 7]);
 b8:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 8]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 8]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 8]);
 b7:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 9]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 9]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- 9]);
 b6:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-10]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-10]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-10]);
 b5:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-11]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-11]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-11]);
 b4:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-12]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-12]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-12]);
 b3:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-13]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-13]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-13]);
 b2:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-14]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-14]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-14]);
 b1:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-15]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-15]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-15]);
 b0:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-16]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-16]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS-16]);

    goto *labels3[num_conns];
 c15:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 1]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c14:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 2]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c13:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 3]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c12:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 4]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c11:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 5]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c10:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 6]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c9:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 7]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c8:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 8]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c7:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 9]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c6:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-10]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c5:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-11]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c4:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-12]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c3:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-13]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c2:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-14]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c1:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-15]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
 c0:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS-16]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;

}
```

What I am doing here is processing in parallel MAX_THREADS number of connections. Loops were unrolled on purpose for speed. But the code is very long. I need to reduce it using macros, kind of like this:

```
extern int conn_fds[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern int fl_conn_indexes[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern int fl_req_bufs[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern struct epoll_event estab_events[MAX_THREADS];
extern req_buf_t req_bufs[MAX_REQ_BUFS];
extern int fl_req_bufs_top;
extern int conn_statuses[MAX_CLIENTS];
extern int fl_conn_indexes_top;
extern  tcpl_nc_t nc_http_list;
extern struct sockaddr_in conn_addresses[MAX_CLIENTS];

void accept_connections(unsigned int num_conns) {
    int fds[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn_idx=0;
    int new_bottom;
    socklen_t slenghts[MAX_THREADS];
    void *labels1[MAX_THREADS] = {&&a0,&&a1,&&a2,&&a3,&&a4,&&a5,&&a6,&&a7,&&a8,&&a9,&&a10,&&a11,&&a12,&&a13,&&a14,&&a15};
    void *labels2[MAX_THREADS] = {&&b0,&&b1,&&b2,&&b3,&&b4,&&b5,&&b6,&&b7,&&b8,&&b9,&&b10,&&b11,&&b12,&&b13,&&b14,&&b15};
    void *labels3[MAX_THREADS] = {&&c0,&&c1,&&c2,&&c3,&&c4,&&c5,&&c6,&&c7,&&c8,&&c9,&&c10,&&c11,&&c12,&&c13,&&c14,&&c15};

    new_bottom=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    if (new_bottom<=0) return;

    goto *labels1[num_conns];

LOOP(1,MAX_THREADS) {
 a{ITERATOR}:
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- {ITERATOR}]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top- {ITERATOR}];
}
    fl_conn_indexes_top=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    goto *labels2[num_conns];
LOOP(1,MAX_THREADS) {      
 b{ITERATOR}:
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- {ITERATOR}]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- 1{ITERATOR}]],&slenghts[MAX_THREADS- {ITERATOR}]);
}
    goto *labels3[num_conns];
LOOP(1,MAX_THREADS) {
 c{ITERATOR}:
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS- {ITERATOR}]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
}

}
```

The {ITERATOR} goes from 1 to MAX_THREADS inside the LOOP()
The labels are neded because the number of connections can be lower than MAX_THREADS and I have to skip empty variables otherwise I will get segfaults.

Can this be implemented with the preprocessor of GCC easily? If not, maybe I could use m4, but how to integrate m4 with GCC for comfortable development. Because, I am going to edit these macros very often along many other files within the source code and easiness of coding is needed.

Will appreciate very much your help

Comment: I forgot to mention that the syntax LOOP() is invented by me to explain what kind of unrolling I need, but this code will not compile, and what I seek is precisely code that will look nice and compile

Comment: I am looking at m4 preprocessor, it is very good, but the bad thing is, if you  write all your .c files inside .m4 files the syntax in vim is not highlighted, also you have to escape the '#' with quotes because it is a comment in m4 and such line is not interpreted by the preprocessor. too bad GCC has no good preprocessor embedded in it.

Comment: I can't believe it. m4 doesn't support native loops. How is it possible that such a simple task can't be achieved by such a powerful tool like a compiler or a dedicated macroprocessor like m4? I am stunned. Will have to use php preg_matching everything and create new files under another directory.

Comment: `m4` doesn't support native loops because recursion is the idiomatic way of doing it (as in functional languages). I'd ask though, why you need to use a preprocessor rather than just passing `-funroll-loops` (or a high `-O` level) to your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

If you do require an answer in `m4`:

```
dnl usage: unroll(var, initial, max, code)
dnl e.g. unroll(`i', 0, 10, ``total += arr[i]'')
dnl The above goes from 0 to 9, it does not include the final 10.
define(`unroll',
       `define(`$1', `$2')ifelse(eval($2 < $3),
                                 1,
                                 `$4`'unroll(`$1',incr($2),$3,`$4')',
                                 `undefine(`$1')')')dnl

void accept_connections(unsigned int num_conns) {
    int fds[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS];
    int conn_idx=0;
    int new_bottom;
    socklen_t slenghts[MAX_THREADS];
    void *labels1[MAX_THREADS] = {unroll(`i', 0, 16, `&&a`'i,')};
    void *labels2[MAX_THREADS] = {unroll(`i', 0, 16, `&&b`'i,')};
    void *labels3[MAX_THREADS] = {unroll(`i', 0, 16, `&&c`'i,')};

    new_bottom=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    if (new_bottom<=0) return;

    define(`MAX_NUM_CONNS', 16)
    goto *labels1[num_conns];
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
 a`'eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
    conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - count]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top - count];
')dnl

    fl_conn_indexes_top=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    goto *labels2[num_conns];
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
define(`index', `MAX_THREADS - count')dnl
 b`'eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
    conn_fds[conn_indexes[index]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[index]],&slenghts[index]);
')dnl
undefine(`index')

    goto *labels3[num_conns];
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
 c`'eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
    conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - count]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
')dnl

}
```

Pay special attention to the macros now within the code: `define`, `unroll`, `eval`, `MAX_NUM_CONNS`, `count`, `index`, `i`. Also notice the quirky quoting which m4 likes.

I can suggest an improvement to this (regardless of whether or not you use `m4`). Your use case here of gotos following directly after each other is one already exactly covered by a more well-known control structure: the `switch` (because fallthrough is the default behaviour without a `break`):

```
    define(`MAX_NUM_CONNS', 16)
    switch (num_conns) {
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
    case eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
        conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - count]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top - count];
')dnl
    }

    fl_conn_indexes_top=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
    switch (num_conns) {
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
define(`index', `MAX_THREADS - count')dnl
    case eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
        conn_fds[conn_indexes[index]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[index]],&slenghts[index]);
')dnl
    }
undefine(`index')

    switch (num_conns) {
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
    case eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
        conn_statuses[conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - count]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
')dnl
    }
```

If you do this conversion to a switch, you can remove your label arrays.

Finally, perhaps it could all be one switch:

```
    define(`MAX_NUM_CONNS', 16)
    switch (num_conns) {
unroll(`count', 1, incr(MAX_NUM_CONNS()), `dnl
define(`index', `MAX_THREADS - count')dnl
    case eval(MAX_NUM_CONNS() - count):
        conn_indexes[index]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top - count];
        conn_fds[conn_indexes[index]]=accept(nc_http_list.sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*) &conn_addresses[conn_indexes[index]],&slenghts[index]);
        conn_statuses[conn_indexes[index]]=CONN_STATUS_READING;
')dnl
    }
undefine(`index')
    fl_conn_indexes_top=fl_conn_indexes_top-num_conns;
```

Note that I've moved the `fl_conn_indexes_top` modification to after the whole unrolled loop is finished - I'm not sure if that's a valid thing to do, because it depends on when that variable is read from or written to. You can make the judgement call there.

---

As I mentioned in a comment, this can be done with compiler flags too. GCC supports the `-funroll-loops` option, which does this for you at the compiler level. GCC also supports `-fprofile-use`, which (when fed a profile from `-fprofile-generate`) will unroll loops which proved to cause performance issues.

---

Finally:

I think this is all premature optimization. I strongly doubt that a loop's comparison check is the bottleneck when *each iteration calls `accept`*!

Answer (score 1):

You can [abuse the C preprocessor with the chaos-pp preprocessor library](http://chaos-pp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/chaos-pp/)

```
#include <chaos/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/config.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/lambda/ops.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/logical/bool.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/recursion/expr.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/repetition/for.h>

#define PRED(s, x) CHAOS_PP_BOOL(x)
#define OP(s, x)   CHAOS_PP_DEC(x)

#define CONN_IDX(s , idx) \
a##idx: \
  conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - (16 - idx)]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top - (16 - idx)]; 

CHAOS_PP_EXPR(CHAOS_PP_FOR(PRED, OP, CONN_IDX, 15))
```

The (formatted) output being:

```
a15: 
conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - (16 - 15)]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top - (16 - 15)]; 
a14: 
conn_indexes[MAX_THREADS - (16 - 14)]=fl_conn_indexes[fl_conn_indexes_top - (16 - 14)];
...
```